# xcode pod swift and obj-c

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

i have a `podfile`

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!
#use_frameworks!
target 'app' do
    pod 'ApiAI/Core'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn'
    pod 'OneSignal', '2.5.0'
    pod 'Realm'
    pod 'SinchRTC'
    pod 'SinchVerification'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'
    pod 'MGSwipeTableCell'
    pod 'NYTPhotoViewer', '1.2.0'
    pod 'ProgressHUD'
    pod 'RCSinchService'
    pod 'Reachability'
    pod 'RNCryptor-objc'
    pod 'SoundManager'
  pod 'ATHMultiSelectionSegmentedControl'
  pod "DownPicker"

end
```

but i have error `no such module 'DownPicker'`, if i uncomment the line `use_frameworks!` he did find this module, but give the another error

[image]

how i can fix it ? is that possible ? as far as I understand, this line is responsible for the language of writing

Answer (score 0):

> `pod 'SoundManager'
>     pod 'ATHMultiSelectionSegmentedControl'
>     pod "DownPicker"`

Note that you've used double quotes around `DownPicker` but single quotes for every other module. Perhaps that's the problem.